# FrameWork + Embedded Binaries

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, frameworks

I have this issue when I attach my custom framework to a Test project.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FrameworkName.framework/FrameworkName
>     Referenced from: /Users/Me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9C4B0FD8-200B-4FF1-AFEC-7D2316698CDA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9BAA9518-2FD0-4AAC-ABD8-F3842FA77A9E/TestProject.app/TestProject
>     Reason: image not found

I need to attach the framework to the **Embedded Binaries** to fixe this issue.

My question is:

- Why for the other framework is not mandatory to add it to **Embedded Binaries** ?
- What is missing in my framework project, or what I need to change in the build settings of the framework project ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the issue, i need to change the Mach-O Type in the build settings to **Static Library.**[image]